# ReactiveCocoa, is there a better way to RAC first and refresh later

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Here's the situation

> I've a ViewModel (ok, follow the MVVM architecture), which has an array property, called "specialtySegments", and a flag property called "generic", I wanna when the generic value is changed, update the specialtySegments value again

Code snippet

```
- (instancetype)initWithTerritory:(SAPTerritory *)territory {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _territory = territory;
        _generic = NO;            
        _selectedProduct = [_products firstObject];

        RAC(self, specialtySegments) = [self querySpecialtySegments];

    }

    return self;
}

- (RACSignal *)querySpecialtySegments {
    return [[[[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [self asynQuerySpecialtySegments:^(NSArray *model) {
            [subscriber sendNext:model];
            [subscriber sendCompleted];
        }];


        return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{

        }];
    }] deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] publish] autoconnect];
}


- (void)refreshData {
    [self asynQuerySpecialtySegments:^(NSArray *model) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.specialtySegments = model;
        });
    }];                    
}
```

And in the ViewController

```
@weakify(self);
[[RACObserve(self.viewModel, specialtySegments) filter:^BOOL(id value) {
    return (value != nil);
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    @strongify(self) {
        [self.indicatorView stopAnimating];
        self.indicatorView.hidden = YES;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

And some place to change the generic value, like

```
if (specialtyButton.selected == NO) {
    self.viewModel.generic = NO;
    genericButton.selected = NO;
    specialtyButton.selected = YES;
    [self.viewModel refreshData];
}
```

That's what I know to do now, it's not kind of fancy, I think.

Could I observe the generic property in the ViewModel, and subscripNext and first the signal again.

I've try like this, but code didn't enter the **querySpecialtySegments**, I put a breakpoint in the method.

```
[RACObserve(self, generic) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [self querySpecialtySegments];
}];
```

and if I do like this, the **asynQuerySpecialtySegments** method would enter twice, as the RAC before, would run it once, I think

```
    [RACObserve(self, generic) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        [self asynQuerySpecialtySegments:^(NSArray *model) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.specialtySegments = model;
            });
        }];
    }];
```

I'm a newbie to ReactiveCocoa, trying using in the project, so is there a better way to the thing I described above, thanks guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after one day reading I think I've found the answer by myself

The key point is

> Most signals start out "cold," which means that they will not do any work until subscription.

So this part code should change like this

```
[RACObserve(self, generic) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [[self querySpecialtySegments] subscribeNext:^(id x) { // subscription is the key to trigger
        self.specialtySegments = x;  // would trigger the observer in view controller to do something
    }];
}];
```

**Updated:**
Personal idea is to observe **generic** property in ViewModel and then trigger View to update something is not a best option, some kind of black magic, without calling refresh or something, but the view refresh automatically. With a public method **-reloadData** is a good choice

```
- (void)refreshData {

    @weakify(self);
    [[self querySpecialtySegments] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        @strongify(self) {
            self.specialtySegments = x;
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Better to use not 2 times subscribeNext, but flattenMap: will be really helpful.

Comment: what's different between them?

Comment: flattenMap: is used for chaining signals, or better say transform one signal or signal sequence to another. In your situation no matter what to use, but using flattenMap: will be logically correct;

Answer (score 0):

All correct, it's not works on start, because you are setting instance variable with underscore, if you in init method will call self.generic = NO; , RACObserve will works just as planned.
This happens, because when you setting instance variable, setter will not be called, and methods for KVO like - willChangeValue: and -didChangeValue: also will not be called.

Comment: What I supports to run is  `[RACObserve(self, generic) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [self querySpecialtySegments];
}];` would trigger the query function works again when the generic value is changed, such as `self.viewModel.generic = NO`; I believe this line is calling the setter method. the problem I have is `[self querySpecialtySegments];` method wouldn't be run, which I've set a breakpoint in the method